# Tomcat on web problems

Tags: tomcat

I am using Tomcat and want to write my servlet in Persian. I tried and written but on web page strange characters are displaying. I googled but being a begginer this is very difficult for me to understand written articles as how to use Persian language in Java.

Is there any easy way to change my servlet language to Persian?

Best regards

kashan Nizami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the following steps to configure your Tomcat to serve your UTF-8 pages correctly either this is Persian, Arabic or any language that is written from right to left:

(1) Edit your server.xml as following

```
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
    maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
    enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
    connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" 
    compression="on" 
    compressionMinSize="128" 
    noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" 
    compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"
    URIEncoding="UTF-8"
    />
```

2)  CharsetFilter force the java webapp to handle all requests and responses as UTF-8 encoded. This requires that we define a character set filter like the following:

```
package charsetFilter.classes;

     import java.io.IOException;
     import javax.servlet.Filter;
     import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
     import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
     import javax.servlet.ServletException;
     import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
     import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

    public class CharsetFilter implements Filter{
        private String encoding;

        public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException{
                encoding = config.getInitParameter("requestEncoding");
                if( encoding==null ) encoding="UTF-8";
        }

        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain       next)
        throws IOException, ServletException{           
                if(null == request.getCharacterEncoding())
                request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);             
            response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                next.doFilter(request, response);
        }

            public void destroy(){}
    }
```

This filter makes sure that if the browser hasn't set the encoding used in the request, that it's set to UTF-8.
    The other thing done by this filter is to set the default response encoding ie. the encoding in which the returned html/whatever is. 
    The alternative is to set the response encoding etc. in each controller of the application.

3)  Then add this filter to the web.xml like:

```
<filter>
            <filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>charsetFilter.classes.CharsetFilter</filter-class>
                <init-param>
                    <param-name>requestEncoding</param-name>
                    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
                </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Then write your servlet as:

```
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

and use whatever language you want to use in your servlet.

**UPDATE:**
You can use this for getting parameters:

```
String input = new String(request.getParameter("foo").getBytes("iso-8859-1"), "utf-8");
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Its working fine for servlet response but not for servlet request. I mean when I use str=request.getParameter("name"); then now works